# Less.js not called when not using localhost

Tags: django, less

I have the follwing code in my Django base.html template:

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/less" media="all" href="{% static 'less/ussd_auto.less' %}" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/less-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

When I'm using `http://127.0.0.0.1:8000/` to access my website everything work perfectl and less is compiled on client side.

If I use `http://192.168.1.30:8000/` I have access to my website but without .less file being processed...

I am completely lost... If you have an idea from where the problem is it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.. I just forgot to put info in my settings.py regarding:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1','localhost','192.168.1.0/24')
```

Once I modified that, my app is back to normal :)